# How do I check if user is using a headset instead of mouse?

Tags: aframe

So, I'll determine if my cursor's fuse will be activated only if the user is using a headset. I want to provide two different behaviors depending on whether he's navigating with a mouse or a HMD. How could I check for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the presence of a headset with `AFRAME.utils.device.checkHeadsetConnected()` ([docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.6.0/core/utils.html#aframe-utils-device-checkheadsetconnected)), but this doesn't tell you if they're actually using the connected headset.

Your `a-scene` entity will emit the `'enter-vr'` event when a user goes into fullscreen/VR mode ([docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.6.0/core/scene.html#events)), so you can check at that time if they have a headset connected and know whether they are in headset VR mode:

```
window.addEventListener('enter-vr', e => {
  if (AFRAME.utils.device.checkHeadsetConnected()) { /* modify cursor */ }
});
```

However, this doesn't cover the use case of mobile with a simple viewer (which won't trigger `checkHeadsetConnected`), so you will also want to check `ARAME.utils.device.isMobile()` ([docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.6.0/core/utils.html#aframe-utils-device-ismobile))

```
window.addEventListener('enter-vr', e => {
  if (AFRAME.utils.device.checkHeadsetConnected() ||
      ARAME.utils.device.isMobile()) { /* modify cursor */ }
});
```

You may also want to add another listener for `exit-vr` on non-mobile devices and revert the cursor to click mode.